# Assign cytoband information from one data.frame to genomic position from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames (`cytoband` and `windows`). So I would like to find for each value of the `maploc` column from the `windows` data.frame the corresponding `cytoband` from the `cytoband` data.frame (see below).

```
head(windows)
             chrom  maploc      X4_TU_9 CNV
chr1_1        chr1  291587  0.055690883   0
chr1_2        chr1  640937  0.039105630   0
chr1_3x       chr1  792810 -0.009465735   0
chr1_14xxxxx  chr1  924029 -0.033792175   0
chr1_25xxx    chr1 1035540 -0.010869910   0
chr1_42xxxx   chr1 1184607 -0.020095050   0

head(cytoband)
  chrom chromStart chromEnd Cytoband      G
1  chr1          0  2300000   p36.33   gneg
2  chr1    2300000  5400000   p36.32 gpos25
3  chr1    5400000  7200000   p36.31   gneg
4  chr1    7200000  9200000   p36.23 gpos25
5  chr1    9200000 12700000   p36.22   gneg
6  chr1   12700000 16200000   p36.21 gpos50
```

Ideally, R should find the corresponding chromosome and nucleotide interval (`chromStart - chromEnd`) for each `maploc` value and assign the matching `cytoband` information to it.

Thank you very much for your help!!!

David

Answer (score 0):

Your data as presented doesn't seem to be appropriate to *demonstrate* your problem (even if the data are correct)--the first row in your "chromStart" - "chromEnd" range in your cytoband `data.frame` satisfies all of the "maploc" values from your windows `data.frame`.

That said, here's a minimal example with some made-up data that you should be able to extend to your actual data.

#### Make up some data

```
set.seed(1)
windows <- data.frame(
  chrom = "chr1",
  maploc = sort(floor(runif(10, 500, 5000))),
  X4_TU_9 = rnorm(10)
)
cytoband <- data.frame(
  chrom = "chr1",
  chromStart = seq(0, 6000, 1000),
  chromEnd = seq(1000, 7000, 1000),
  Cytoband = paste("p36", sample(20:40, 7), sep = ".")
)

head(windows, 3)
#   chrom maploc    X4_TU_9
# 1  chr1    778 -0.8204684
# 2  chr1   1407  0.4874291
# 3  chr1   1694  0.7383247
head(cytoband, 3)
#   chrom chromStart chromEnd Cytoband
# 1  chr1          0     1000   p36.30
# 2  chr1       1000     2000   p36.31
# 3  chr1       2000     3000   p36.29
```

#### Use `findInterval` to match the "maploc" values to the intervals defined in the "cytoband" `data.frame`

```
WhichRange <- findInterval(windows$maploc, c(0, cytoband$chromEnd))
WhichRange
#  [1] 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

#### Use that information to match and copy over the "Cytoband" values from "cytoband" to "windows"

```
windows$Cytoband <- cytoband$Cytoband[WhichRange]
#    chrom maploc    X4_TU_9 Cytoband
# 1   chr1    778 -0.8204684   p36.30
# 2   chr1   1407  0.4874291   p36.31
# 3   chr1   1694  0.7383247   p36.31
# 4   chr1   2174  0.5757814   p36.29
# 5   chr1   3077 -0.3053884   p36.23
# 6   chr1   3331  1.5117812   p36.23
# 7   chr1   3473  0.3898432   p36.23
# 8   chr1   4542 -0.6212406   p36.34
# 9   chr1   4586 -2.2146999   p36.34
# 10  chr1   4751  1.1249309   p36.34
```